# Step functions for non-proportional hazards

Tags: cox-model, proportional-hazards

I have a stratified Cox model with covariates ("big") which violate proportional hazard assumptions:

```
model0 <- coxph(Surv(t_start, t_stop, status) ~ big + strata(prov), data=labor)
```

cox.zph output is this:

```
       chisq df     p
big     10.8  1 0.001
GLOBAL  10.8  1 0.001
```

I performed step function to address this:

```
labor_cut=survSplit(Surv(t_stop,status) ~ ., data=labor, cut = c(410, 1461, 2191), episode='t_group')

model0.strat <- coxph(Surv(t_start, t_stop, status) ~ big:strata(t_group), data=labor_cut)
```

I now have two questions.  1) Can I still stratify on clusters (e.g. strata(prov)) while also using step function to stratify by time cut-offs?

And 2) how is using survSplit() to cut the dataset at various timepoints different from simply splitting the dataset by hand and re-running each Cox regression individually?  I am getting different coefficients from each method.

In addition, splitting the dataset at the same timepoints by hand yields results that are now proportional.  However, using survSplit and interacting my non-proportional variable with strata(t_group) still yields results that are non-proportional.  Why is this?